# Mutually exclusive or not?

Tags: terminology

I am searching for the proper term that describes the following set of criteria:

1) A word starts with "ab"
2) A word starts with "a"

or

1) The animal is a dog
2) The animal is a canine

As you can see it is not a case of true mutual exclusion because there is only a one-way exclusion. How can this relationship be called?

Comment: Actually, there is no exclusion at all. It's rather a matter of inclusiveness. All elements in set 1) are elements in set 2). You could say rule 1) is more _specific_ than rule 2).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the domain of mathematics, assuming 1) is A and 2) is B:

```
A is a proper (or strict) subset of B.
```

or equivalently:

```
B is a proper superset of A
```

Alternative terms are *inclusion* or sometimes *containment* of A inside B.

As an Euler diagram:

[image]

Reference:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset

Comment: Also there's a useful example about the proper subset here: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProperSubset.html